# Vue.js and spring boot project architecture

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, architecture, project-structure

I am pretty familiar with spring boot. Now I want to use `Vue.js`, `thymeleaf` (only forfew things like fragments) and `Spring Boot`, of course.

I am a but unsure about the project structure. Do I really need a `frontend client` and a `backend client`? While doing research I often saw trees like this with three `pom.xml`:

```
       ├── project
       ├── backend
       │   ├── src
       │   └── pom.xml
       ├── frontend
       │   ├── src
       │   └── pom.xml
       └── pom.xml
```

Right now my project looks like this:

```
   ├── application.properties
   ├── com
   │   └── elps
   │       └── fileconverter
   │           ├── controller
   │           │   └── FileConverterController.class
   │           └── FileconverterApplication.class
   ├── static
   │   └── css
   │       ├── normalize.css
   │       └── skeleton.css
   └── templates
       ├── fragments
       │   ├── footer.html
       │   └── header.html
       └── index.html
```

What is a common way to build a project using `Vue.js` and `Spring Boot`?
The only requirement I got is not to execute the script `within` the HTML files.

Answer (score 1):

I follow https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/04/spring-boot-vuejs/ which has 3 pom.xml. But there is nothing wrong with your project structure as well. I personally use src/main/java, src/main/webapp/ for separating the layers and use gradle to build an application with embedded web-container. This works well for a simple web application - where scalability is out of scope.